# The Dual Nature of svn:ignore

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Reading around, the svn:ignore command seems to work one of two ways:

1. If the file or directory is not already under version control, meta data will be added to the repository ignoring the file or directory for all other team members who check out the project.
2. If the file or directory is already under version control, the ignore will only be applied locally and no meta data added to the repository. Other team members will not have the file or directory ignored and can freely commit changes, and those changes will update your locally ignored file when executing an update.

Is this correct?

**Edit:** Follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054349/ommit-versioned-files-or-folders-from-commit-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the following excerpt from the [Tortoise Documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html) there is no second nature. `svn:ignore` is solely operative on *unversioned files*.

> Versioned files and folders can never
>   be ignored - that's a feature of
>   Subversion. If you versioned a file by
>   mistake, read the section called
>   “Ignore files which are already
>   versioned” for instructions on how to
>   “unversion” it.