# Omit Versioned Files or Folders from Commit List

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Follow-to this question: [The Dual Nature of svn:ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052999/the-dual-nature-of-svnignore)

Is there any way to accomplish the second scenario? i.e. Stop Tortoise SVN or plain SVN from listing a fixed set of files which have local modifications but are under version control from appearing in the commit list?

I am on a project where I am the sole remote developer with a group of developers in another company, as a consequence all the other developers can share certain files which I need to make local modifications to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tortoise supports this via the [ignore-on-commit changelist](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html).  Any items in the ignore-on-commit changelist will be unchecked by default in the Tortoise commit dialog.  To add an item to the list, right-click it in the commit dialog or the modifications dialog, mouse over "Move to changelist" and select "ignore-on-commit"

Comment: @Stephen Swensen: Interesting follow up. I didn't know that Tortoise is shipped with this often demanded feature! Whereas this is Tortoise only.